# Extjs 7, How to pass dynamic data from one controller to another controller using view Model

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6-classic, extjs7

**I'm new to sencha, I'm trying to pass data from one page to another page using ctrl to ctrl, onclick submit button the values should carry to another page view**

**Reg Page View**

```
Ext.define('sample.view.register.Registration', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
xtype: 'register',
itemId: 'registers',
layout: 'vbox',
requires: [
    'sample.view.register.RegistrationModel',
    'sample.view.register.RegistrationController',
    'sample.view.user.User',
    'sample.view.user.UserController',
    'sample.store.Personnel'
],
controller: 'register',
viewModel: 'register',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        padding: 10,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'User Name',
            name: 'nameReg',
            bind: {
                value: '{formData.nameReg}'
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'password1',
            inputType: 'password',
            itemId: 'password1',
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
        },

        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: 'onSubmit'
        }],

    }],
```

**Reg Controller**

```
Ext.define('sample.view.register.RegistrationController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.register',
onSubmit: function () {
    var name = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#nameReg')[0].lastValue;
    var pass = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#password1')[0].lastValue;
    var age = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#age')[0].lastValue;

    const da = this.getViewModel().get('formData');
     console.log(da) // im getting data here user, this data I want to carry to another page( User page )
 // Ext.create('sample.view.user.User', {
    //     id: Ext.id(),
    //     myVariable: store,
    // });
```

}

**Reg Model Page**

```
Ext.define('sample.view.register.RegistrationModel', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias: 'viewmodel.register',
data: {
    formData: {
        nameReg: '',
        pass: null,
    },
    afterSubmit: true,
    //     names: 'sample',
    //     loremIpsum: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
},
```

});

**User Page View** 
**here I want to show data , which is carrying from reg page and bind value to input**

```
Ext.define('sample.view.user.User', {
xtype: 'user',
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
// extend: 'Ext.Container',
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
itemId: 'userPage',
requires: [
    'sample.view.register.RegistrationController',
    'sample.view.register.RegistrationModel'
],

// viewModel: {
//     data: {
//         title: 'Default Title'
//     }
// },
// initComponent: function () {
//     if (this.title) {
//         console.log('==========', this.title)
//     }
// },


width: 600,
bodyPadding: 10,
// layout: 'form',
autoScroll: 'true',

items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'User Name',
    name: 'nameReg',
    itemId: 'nameReg',
    bind: {
        value: '{formData.nameReg}'
    }
}]
```

});

here I have tried with view model, but I'm not getting how this exactly work,Let me Know If you need more info on to this, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two options which I use in cases like this:

1. Share a view model: whenever it makes sense, use one view model for two related views. Via data binding, the first view writes data to the view model, while the second view reads the same data. So bacially you merge those two view models into one.
2. Have an overall view model as a parent class for both view models, holding the data that is shared by both views. Let’s call this 'App.UserModel'. Your two view models should then extend 'App.UserModel' (instead of 'Ext.app.ViewModel'). Again, simple data binding should do the job just fine.

Comment: thanks for you answer, can you share some code for options 2 one, for me really hard to get what exactly should do